# How to print information displayed on Datagrid using react-admin

Tags: react-admin

Please is there a way to print data displayed on Datagrid using react-admin just the same way exporter utility works on the List control?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use the exporter then? Are you using the Datagrid component standalone, without List? In that case, where does the data come from?

Comment: Hi Francois, sorry for replying to this at this time. Just seeing it now. The Datagrid is within the List component. The data is coming from one of the resources. I just want to be able to send the data to printer instead of exporting to csv. I will appreciate it if u can guide me on how to do this in your React-Admin (very powerful tool indeed)

Comment: Do you need to print all the pages (not just the one displayed) listing the records for the current resource, or just the current page?

Comment: the displayed page is ok for printing. Thanks

Comment: Then you don't need anything from react-admin, you just need a print CSS. https://www.sitepoint.com/css-printer-friendly-pages/